Android-TV YouTube app display playlist Intent
When I open the following URL in a web browser I see a playlist, that is a list of videos:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLVewHiZp3_LNAj6aNnjmwDj6LqehLqXXi
If however I activate the YouTube app of android TV it shows something else. The YouTube app
starts to play the first video in the playlist while what I need is to see the list itself.
Here are sample alternative activations that I trayed (in Kotlin):
        // work: play first vid in list
        val intent1 = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/listType=playlist?list=PLVewHiZp3_LNAj6aNnjmwDj6LqehLqXXi"))
        startActivity(intent1)

        // work: play first vid in list
        val intent2 = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube://listType=playlist?list=PLr2jljBBtVJ9Tq1JGyOFdbxcgkk9MyNuJ"))
        startActivity(intent2)

        val intent3 = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube://playlist?list=PLr2jljBBtVJ9Tq1JGyOFdbxcgkk9MyNuJ"))
        startActivity(intent3)

How can I activate the YouTube app so it shows the list?
